# syntax error near unexpected token `(' in an Oracle Deployment Procedure

Tags: linux, bash

I have script that is a part of a deployment procedure used in both Oracle Grid Control 11g and Cloud Control 12c. It's working fine in 11g but when I run it in 12c I get this error message:

> /u01/tmp/JOB_F0820842485038B3E04301723F0A70AE/configure_init_conf.sh:
>   line 63: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>   /u01/tmp/JOB_F0820842485038B3E04301723F0A70AE/configure_init_conf.sh:
>   line 63:`  done < (cd
>   ${MIDDLEWARE_HOME}/user_projects/domains/${DOMAIN_NAME}/servers/; find
>   *WLS* -prune -type d)'

That part of the script looks like this:

```
# find_domains
# Purpose: Will find WLS domaons
#
find_domains()
{
  while read MANAGED_SERVER
  do
    [ -z "$MANAGED_SERVERS" ] && MANAGED_SERVERS="$MANAGED_SERVER" || MANAGED_SERVERS="$MANAGED_SERVERS $MANAGED_SERVER"
  done < (cd ${MIDDLEWARE_HOME}/user_projects/domains/${DOMAIN_NAME}/servers/; find *WLS* -prune -type d)
}
```

Here's the funny part, if I upload that script to the server and run it - I don't get any error thrown. It's only when running it through the deployment procedure in 12c. So my question is really: could you see anything wrong or should I take it as a bug/problem within the 12c? I'm not really a script guru, just need some backup if I shall create a service request with Oracle... Might add that the script part originally looked like this:

```
# find_domains
# Purpose: Will find WLS domaons
#
find_domains()
{
  while read MANAGED_SERVER
  do
    [ -z "$MANAGED_SERVERS" ] && MANAGED_SERVERS="$MANAGED_SERVER" || MANAGED_SERVERS="$MANAGED_SERVERS $MANAGED_SERVER"
  done < <( cd ${MIDDLEWARE_HOME}/user_projects/domains/${DOMAIN_NAME}/servers/; find *WLS* -prune -type d)
}
```

I changed the "< <( cd..." part, but still the same error message

Comment: Why don't you directly `find ${MIDDLEWARE_HOME}/user_projects/domains/${DOMAIN_NAME}/servers/ ...` instead of `cd`ing before?

Comment: Sounds like 12c is running a version of bash that doesn't support process substitution.

Comment: what if you change it to
`pushd blablabla; find ... | while read MANAGED_SERVER; do ...; done; popd` ?